# How to return the results in a new column

Tags: sql, self-join

I have the following working query:

```sql
    SELECT *
    FROM EMPLOYEE_HISTORY
    WHERE supervisor_login_name IN (select login_name from EMPLOYEE_HISTORY WHERE supervisor_login_name IN ('a','b','c','d','e')                     
    and is_active_record = 'Y'
    and is_employed = 'Y' ) and is_active_record = 'Y'
    and is_employed = 'Y'
    OR supervisor_login_name IN (select supervisor_login_name from EMPLOYEE_HISTORY WHERE supervisor_login_name IN ('a','b','c','d','e') 
    and is_active_record = 'Y'
    and is_employed = 'Y')
    and is_active_record = 'Y'
    and is_employed = 'Y'
    
    OR supervisor_login_name IN (select login_name from EMPLOYEE_HISTORY WHERE supervisor_login_name IN(select login_name from EMPLOYEE_HISTORY WHERE supervisor_login_name in ('a','b','c','d','e') and is_active_record = 'Y'
    and is_employed = 'Y')
    and is_active_record = 'Y'
    and is_employed = 'Y')
    and is_active_record = 'Y'
    and is_employed = 'Y'
```

and I have tried to:

```sql
    SELECT *
    FROM EMPLOYEE_HISTORY 
    
    WHERE supervisor_login_name IN (select T1.login_name from EMPLOYEE_HISTORY as T1 Join EMPLOYEE_HISTORY as T2 ON T2.supervisor_login_name = T1.supervisor_login_name WHERE T1.supervisor_login_name IN ('a','b','c','d','e')                    
    and T1.is_active_record = 'Y'
    and T1.is_employed = 'Y' 
    Union Select supervisor_login_name from EMPLOYEE_HISTORY As "ops" where supervisor_login_name in ('a','b','c','d','e')) and is_active_record = 'Y'
    and is_employed = 'Y'
    OR supervisor_login_name IN (select T1.supervisor_login_name from EMPLOYEE_HISTORY as T1 Join EMPLOYEE_HISTORY as T2 ON T2.supervisor_login_name = T1.supervisor_login_name WHERE T1.supervisor_login_name IN ('a','b','c','d','e')
    and T1.is_active_record = 'Y'
    and T1.is_employed = 'Y'
    Union Select supervisor_login_name from EMPLOYEE_HISTORY As "ops" where supervisor_login_name in ('a','b','c','d','e'))
    and is_active_record = 'Y'
    and is_employed = 'Y'
    
    OR supervisor_login_name IN (select login_name from EMPLOYEE_HISTORY  WHERE supervisor_login_name IN(select T1.login_name from EMPLOYEE_HISTORY as T1 Join EMPLOYEE_HISTORY as T2 ON T2.supervisor_login_name = T1.supervisor_login_name WHERE T1.supervisor_login_name in ('a','b','c','d','e')
    and T1.is_active_record = 'Y' 
    and T1.is_employed = 'Y'
    Union Select supervisor_login_name from EMPLOYEE_HISTORY As "ops" where supervisor_login_name in ('a','b','c','d','e'))
    and is_active_record = 'Y'
    and is_employed = 'Y')
    and is_active_record = 'Y'
    and is_employed = 'Y'
```

How can I return my "ops" column to the results?
Tip: I am trying to return the manager's manager in the "ops" column

I am trying to get a column "ops". I have login_name(the employee) and supervisor_login_name(the employee's manager) and I want to create a column "ops" with the manager's manager, because the users from supervisor_login_name are already in login_name, So I want to return the cases from login_name that are also in supervisor__login_name and bring their equivalent from supervisor_login_name.

This is the example of what I have and what I want:

```sql
+------------+-----------------------+-----+
| login_name | supervisor_login_name | ops |
+------------+-----------------------+-----+
| a          | e                     | y   |
| b          | f                     | z   |
| c          | g                     | w   |
| d          | h                     | x   |
| e          | y                     |     |
| f          | z                     |     |
| g          | w                     |     |
| h          | x                     |     |
+------------+-----------------------+-----+
```

So basically I want to return the column "ops" that at the moment doesn't exist.I want to create it

This is the table structure:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the result you are expecting? please show all table columns in Employee_history

Comment: Simplify the problem to get better/any response. [mcve]

Comment: I am trying to get a column "ops". I have login_name(the employee) and supervisor_login_name(the employee's manager) and I want to create a column "ops" with the manager's manager, because the users from supervisor_login_name are already in login_name, So I want to return the cases from login_name that are also in supervisor__login_name and bring their equivalent from supervisor_login_name.

Comment: @Psko, Rather thann asking why your code is not working, Please mention the sample data amd expected result, You might get a better and simple solution.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I have updated my post with the example

Comment: @Psko, by looking at the problem, it seems that it can be solved with a simple self join. the query you posted seems unnecessarily duplicate conditions and sub queries, but I may be wrong, it is bit difficult to read. If you write your actual table structure together with the expected result you will get good answers

Comment: @KiranHegde I have updated the question with the table structure. I already said what is the expected result, check the table from the description

Comment: do you want to display the new column ? or add the new column to the table and populate it ? also the table structure you provided does not have a login_name

Comment: @Psko please do update: your need specify table structure as text, not pictures. Pictures is not usable for members who will try to reproduce your request.

Comment: @timnavigate the section won't let me to post those rows as text, just as picture, I don't know why.

Comment: @GabrielDurac I want to display the column in the results, not into the table, I just want to export that new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the login_name is the employee_name based on your table structure.
Also, based on your initial query I assume we are interested in employees that are both active and employed (is_employed = 'Y' and is_active_record = 'Y')

```
SELECT e.employee_name as login_name
      ,e.supervisor_login_name
      ,s.supervisor_login_name as ops
FROM EMPLOYEE_HISTORY e
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_HISTORY s 
     ON e.supervisor_login_name = s.employee_name 
     AND s.is_employed = 'Y' 
     AND s.is_active_record = 'Y' 
WHERE e.is_employed = 'Y' 
      AND e.is_active_record = 'Y'
```

That being said, I think the link would be better done using employee_id and supervisor_id if that is a possibility.

Comment: The "ops" column didn't return any results

Comment: is my assumption that the login_name is the employee_name correct ?

Comment: It is working finally :D thank you sir! (is was login_name but don't know why didn't appear in the picture, after modifying it, now it works like a charm! (raman dator cu o bere :) )

Comment: It was a reason for all the interrogations, if a supervisor had under him a user that is also supervisor, the query returned the users that are under him also, how can I edit it to export those users also?

Comment: so you would like to get the whole hierarchy tree ?  you would want a recursive CTE. What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Amazon Redshift

Comment: Sadly I am not familiar with it. Do you know if it supports recursive common table expressions ?

Comment: It is based on PostgreSQL 8.x so I guess unfortunately doesn't support CTEs. But the first posted query returned the entire hierarchy so I guess I can somehow combine both queries in one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220218/discussion-between-gabriel-durac-and-psko).